# I want to set validation with jquery on textbox (required if checked and max value) asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I found solution with a nice pop up message to make field required. And i want to keep conventions about message.

I was able to do required field with a code below. But i need in that to make also a compare validator with other textbox where in my validation field have to be lower value.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('input[id="<%= checkBox.ClientID %>"]').change(function () {

            if ($('input[id="<%= validateTxtbox.ClientID %>"]').attr('required')) {
                $('input[id="<%= validateTxtbox.ClientID %>"]').removeAttr('required');
            }
            else {
                $('input[id="<%= validateTxtbox.ClientID %>"]').attr('required', 'required');

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Can u help me to execute this?

Answer (score 1):

```js
<script>
    $('#chk').on('change', function () {
        $('#validate').prop('required', !$('#validate').prop('required'));
    });

    $('#validate').on('keyup', function () {
        var validateVal = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        var numVal = parseInt($('#num').val(), 10);
        if (validateVal > numVal) {
            alert('Validate input has a number higher than that number in the other input field');
        }
    });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk"/> Check
<br />
<input type="text" id="validate"/>
<br />
<br />
Num
<br />
<input type="text" id="num" value="10"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try the code below but only required field works:

```
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $('input[id="<%= checkBox.ClientID %>"]').change(function () {
         if ($('input[id="<%= validateTxtbox.ClientID %>"]').attr('required')) {
           $('input[id="<%= validateTxtbox.ClientID %>"]').removeAttr('required');
             }
        else {
            $('input[id="<%= validateTxtbox.ClientID %>"]').attr('required', 'required');
           }
        });
            $('input[id="<%= validateTxtbox.ClientID %>"]').on('keyup', function () {
          var validateVal = parseInt($('input[id="<%= validateTxtbox.ClientID %>"]').val(), 10);
           var numVal = parseInt($('input[id="<%= numberForValidation.ClientID %>"]').val(), 10);
          if (validateVal > numVal) {
         alert('Validate input has a number higher than that number in the other input field');
   }
});
});
 </script>
```